# How to set thread count for remote servers in command-line mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am using the following command for distributed load testing in JMeter:

```
jmeter -JThreadCount="5" -n -t "path.jmx" -R IP1,IP2 -l "path.csv" -e -o "outputpath"
```

But it does not take 5 as the thread count but runs 2 times one for each remote system. When I remove the -R parameter it takes 5 as the thread count.

How to pass the ThreadCount (variables) to the remote servers?

Answer (score 1):

1. I do believe that you need to use `-G` command-line argument in order to pass the
   property to the remove slaves
2. I don't think you need these quotation marks around `5`

Suggested amended command line:

```
jmeter -GThreadCount=5 -n -t "path.jmx" -R IP1,IP2 -l "path.csv" -e -o "outputpath"
```

More information:

- [Full list of JMeter command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)